# Memory Usage to CSV file

Tags: monitoring, ram

I am doing some calculations and want to monitor the RAM usage of different approaches to compare them.
This means, that I want to monitor the ram usage of one single process over a time frame of about 1 minute and want to have an output that I can use with Excel.

In my mind, I am imagining sth. like this:
1) Starting the RAM capturing tool.
2) Starting my calculation via command line.
3) It runs for some time... (up to 1 Minute)
4) I now want to have the following result in a .csv file SECONDS | RAM_USED
5)

0 0MB
1 200MB
2 300MB
3 200MB
4 100MB
5 0MB

I know what the name of the process of the calculations will be, but I guess the PID is different for each type of calculation.

Comment: elaborate your issue, be more exact ... and post some potential expected result/output

Comment: Hey. I can follow what task you are trying to do. But I'm not quite clear what information you want from the internet. I can kind of guess, a list of tools that you might use, whether something already exists to do this.

Comment: Yes. I would like to have help regarding how to do this. What tool to use, and how to use it.